# Is there a fast way to export podcast URLs from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Is there an easy way to export all my subscribed podcast URLs in iTunes?

I am trying to subscribe to the same podcasts on a non-Apple device (Zune used instead of iPhone when running) but having to right click each one and copy and pasting the URL to another computer to add the podcast to it's software is tedious.  I am sure there is a better way.

Also would like to do it for backup purposes since iTunes seems to have to get reinstalled every 6 months or so :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right-click on the Podcasts entry in the side bar
- Select "Export..."
- Select OPML format

This gives you a short file listing all the subscribed podcasts including the URL.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes 11 open Podcasts and then choose "File > Library > Export playlist".

Comment: this also works on itunes 12 (they should change this  name, "export playlist" doesn't make much sense for a list of podcast subscriptions)